# Large binary with C++ on embedded bare-metal system (Xilinx Zync ARM A53)

Tags: c++, bare-metal

I have an application implemented in C++ that is supposed to run on an A53 bare-metal system. My problem is that the resulting binary is very large. When I look at the content per `nm` I see why - there are a lot of standard C++ functions linked that I would not expect to be needed, e.g. for exception handling, RTTI and dynamic memory management. I don't use any of these.
I found [this](https://bitbashing.io/embedded-cpp.html) description which says that these things should be disabled with the appropriate compiler flags, e.g. `-fno-exceptions`, `-fno-non-call-exceptions`, and `-fno-rtti`.
Unfortunately, these have no effect at all on me - the binary keeps the same size and the said symbols are still there.
What can I do to get rid of this ballast?

Comment: Do you use lot of templates? That tend to increase code size. Do you optimize for size with `-Os`? Have you tried link-time optimization with `-flto`? Do you strip the executable (using the `strip` command or the `-s` linker option)?

Comment: You can use `nm` on individual .o files after compilation to see which file pulls in the dependencies. Then maybe inspect the assembly to locate the offending function.

Comment: Can we see part of `nm` output altogether with your exact build commands.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling exception and RTTI does NOT disable it in the standard library, only in your code. If you link against stdlib you bring all that baggage into your binary. Try to pass `-nostdlib` option as well. Note that in case of disabling stdlib some standard functionality may become missing and you'll get linking errors. The missing functionality will either have to be stubbed or implemented.

For more details I recommend reading [Practical Guide to Bare Metal C++](https://arobenko.github.io/bare_metal_cpp). Although written about 10 years ago it can still be relevant for you, especially "Know Your Compiler Output" section.